# Entity Framework - Oracle 11 - Insert Association/Link record between two tables

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a new link between two items that already exist.

The link table has:

```
{
   userid - with a fk to the user table;
   roleid - with a fk to the role table;
}
```

The records that I am linking already exist in the roles, and users tables.

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
   ORA_ASPNET_USERS usersTable = db.ORA_ASPNET_USERS
       .Where(u => u.USERID == UserId).First();
   usersTable.ORA_ASPNET_ROLES
       .Add(db.ORA_ASPNET_ROLES.Where(c => c.ROLEID == RoleId).First());

   db.ORA_ASPNET_USERS.Add(usersTable);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem I am having is that it is trying to insert a new record into the Users tables and it should only be inserting a record into the link table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the user again when you use the `Add` method, it changes the state of that entity to `Added`. You don't need to do that if you don't have disabled tracking changes or lazy loading.By default, the Entity Framework performs detect changes automatically. Try again deleting that line:

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
   ORA_ASPNET_USERS usersTable = db.ORA_ASPNET_USERS.First(u => u.USERID == UserId);
   usersTable.ORA_ASPNET_ROLES
       .Add(db.ORA_ASPNET_ROLES.First(c => c.ROLEID == RoleId));

   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Another thing is you don't need to call the `Where` method, you can pass the same condition to the `First` method. The only problem is if the user or role doesn't exist,  EF will throw you an exception, is better call the `FirstOrDefault` method and check if the returned entity is not null .